# microsoft .net encrypted file format

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

The examples I've seen of doing encryption with .net describe creating streams, which could be put in a file. But best practices require putting more in the ciphertext file in addition to the output of the cipher algorithm. Is there some standard format for the file, with a place for the initialization vector, a hash value if appropriate, and anything I've forgotten? Or is a different format created for each application?

Comment: Encryption is often used with (non-seekable) network streams.  There is no such standard format afaik.

Comment: There are many standard formats, and some of those standard formats include encryption.  For example, encrypted ZIP files or PGP-encoded files.  But being "standard" is not enough to make some format suitable for your particular application.

Comment: However, take a look at the [OpenPGP message format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880)

Comment: Thanks Ben Voight, I should have been clearer. I knew that some groups other than Microsoft had created standards, and already knew about Gnu Privacy Guard and Pretty Good Privacy. I was wondering if there were a file format that goes with .net (or maybe .net supports something like OpenPGP?)